# Detect if the user is navigating through the safari mobile browser on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, safari

I am trying to detect if the user is navigating my website from safari browser on the iphone using jquery / javascript.

I am able to detect the IOS Environment using the user agent string

`/iphone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())`

But this detects the Apple Webkit Environment i.e. it is same for all the browsers on the device. Can anyone suggest any different approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### UPDATED:

---

Try this, for detecting Safari browser in an iPhone:

```
var isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/);
```

It identifies Safari 3.0+ and distinguishes it from Chrome.

## JsFiddle

Comment: Even in chrome it say isSafari for me

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it in Chrome version 36 and it does not for me. But it does show alert in Safari on my iPhone 4s.

Comment: My friend this approach detects the iphone environment and will alert in all the browsers on iphone. I am getting the alert on chrome and opera also on my iphone 5s.

Comment: It will alert for all the browsers used in iphone.

Comment: Updated now and tested

Comment: Yandex browser matches this also. Others are looking ok.

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answer doesn't include detection of an iPhone, including that part.

```
var isIphone = /(iPhone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/);

if(isIphone && isSafari){
    //do something
}
```

If you want to detect a particular iOS version and above, say iOS 7.0 and above then you can use the below code. It detects iOS version 7-19(for upcoming versions).

```
var isIphone= /(iPhone)*(OS ([7-9]|1[0-9])_)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("FxiOS") != -1;  
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("CriOS") != -1;  
var isEdge = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("EdgiOS") != -1;  
var isOpera = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("OPT") != -1;

if (!isFirefox && !isChrome && !isEdge && !isOpera){  
  console.log("Only display in Safari")  
} else {  
  console.log("Only display in Firefox/Chrome/Edge/Opera")  
}
```

Hi, this way worked for me to detect only safari in ios mobile. The value FxiOs, CriOs, etc, I get from the userAgent value.